# Hovering each image showing text below

Tags: html, css, hover

Could you please help me do that kind of blog like here http://be.beantownthemes.com/html/rev-s-premium-team-slider.html
I have the problem with showind text below the images when hovering on each image.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Post the code you have so far and we'll see how we can help.

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In this community, you need to at least TRY IT, then post the code and ask for the specific thing you are stuck with, so ppl help you. Advice look at the source code of that page, break it down TRY IT, THEN if any question, get back here.